# passing new values correctly but also passing undefined into new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have declared a function called filter, taking an array and callback as arguments and passing only even numbers into the new array. The code works but it also passes in the un-even numbers as "undefined" (I am quoting it, not a string). What am I doing wrong?

```
function filter(array, callback) {
  var output = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    output.push(callback(array[i]));
  }
  return output;
}

function isEven(elem) {
  if (elem % 2 === 0)
    return elem;
}

filter([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],isEven); -> [ 0,undefined,2,undefined,4,undefined, 6,undefined]
```

Comment: I am very sure you know that already, just leaving it as a note for others - `Array` has a filter method: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].filter(element => element % 2 == 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want a filter, the callback should only return a boolean:

```js
function filter(array, callback) {
  var output = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if(callback(array[i]))
      output.push(array[i]);
  return output;
}
function isEven(elem) {
  return elem % 2 === 0;
}
console.log(filter([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],isEven));
```

But if you want some mix of map and filter, just check if the mapped value is different than undefined before pushing it to the array.

```js
function mapFilter(array, callback) {
  var output = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var value = callback(array[i]);
    if(value !== undefined)
      output.push(value);
  }
  return output;
}
function isEven(elem) {
  if (elem % 2 === 0)
    return elem;
}
console.log(mapFilter([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],isEven));
```

Answer (score 1):

The way your filter is designed, when a number is not even, the function `isEven()` will push `undefined` into the array because `undefined` is the default return value of a function in JavaScript.

Basically, you are asking `isEven()` for a result and storing it in the array whether or not it actually gave you the result you desired.

There are native functions in JavaScript (see your main post comments/other answers) to help you achieve the same result; however, if you want to go this route it is recommended that you check the result of your callback before you push it into the array.

Comment: Perhaps you might mention that `undefined` is the default return value of a function in JavaScript. A function cannot *not* have a return value.

Answer (score 0):

`[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7].filter(function(digit){return digit%2===0})`

filter function of Array adds elements to new array if it returns true. So I have written condition `digit%2 === 0` which will be `true` for `even` numbers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `isEven` function still returns one array element per input element.  It returns the input value if it was even, otherwise it returns `undefined` (which is the default return value).

Perhaps you were under the impression that if the function does not `return` a value, nothing would get added to the array?  Not so!

You would need to do something like this:

```
function filter(array, callback) {
  var r = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (callback(array[i])) {
      r.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return r;
}

function isEven(elem) {
  if (elem % 2 === 0)
    return elem;
}

filter([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],isEven);
```

But it gets better.  JavaScript `Array` objects have a built-in `filter` method, which does precisely what this `filter` method does.  You just pass it your callback.

```
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ].filter(function (n) {
  return n % 2 === 0;
});
```

This version will output even numbers only... 0, 2, 4, and 6.